# SQL Server Management Studio, creating foreign key relationship, getting Do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constaint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read a few posting here but I did quite understand their solution. I created two tables. I right clicked on the Id and set it PK. On the other table, I set the Code to PK.

**tblCodesAndFiles**

```
Id (PK) int
Code nchar(10)
text varchar(max)
```

**tblCodes**

```
Code (PK) nchar(10)
text varchar(max)
```

In `tblCode`, I right clicked on relationship, added a foreign relationship,

On the primary key table, I picked `tblCodesAndFiles`. On the column, I selected the `Code` column and hit save.

Then I get the following error

> The columns in table 'CodesAndFiles' do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Did you saved the changes in the first table?

Comment: You defined `Id` as PK of `tblCodesAndFiles`. Why you are choosing `Code` ? If you need FK to  `tblCodesAndFiles.Code` declare it `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Based on your tables names I suspect you got the relationship the wrong way around. Try defining your relationship "the other way" i.e. pick `tblCodes` as your primary key table.